# How to check Status of commentator in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments

I have my site in WordPress and i have created a forum page in it for user discussion by using default wordpress comment system. Now in my forum page I want to check whether the commentator user is online or not in real time and also show its status in real time in front of its user Id by using simple text [**Online/Offline**].

Is it possible to display current status of commentator user in WordPress default comment system. Can anybody help me....

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) to determine whether or not someone is logged in...

However, if you need to check whether or not the user has your site open at the moment, you may need to add a filter to `auth_cookie_expiration`, to change the auth cookie expiration rules. Read more on [WPSE](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/122818/how-to-logout-user-on-browser-tab-or-window-closes).